# tomcat 9.0.38 build problems

Tags: tomcat

I have been trying to build tomcat 9.0.38 for a few hours now ;
have gone through every step specified in the install guide except the build.properties file but that doesn't seem to be the problem as the error is not due to writing permissions but rather that the build.xml file links to : [Tomcat Downloadable](http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.lua%20action=download&filename=/commons/daemon/binaries/commons-daemon-1.2.2-bin.tar.gz)

> note that there is no such thing as a string that explicitly points to this version of commons-daemon-1.2.2 within the build.xml file
> but that link returns :The requested URL was not found on this server.
> if you remove /commons-daemon-1.2.2-bin.tar.gz
> you find that commons-daemon-1.2.3-bin.tar.gz is there instead

the error in CMD is as follows :

```
BUILD FAILED
D:\apache-tomcat-9.0.38-src\build.xml:3055: The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\apache-tomcat-9.0.38-src\build.xml:3390: The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\apache-tomcat-9.0.38-src\build.xml:3506: Can't get http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.lua?action=download&filename=/commons/daemon/binaries/commons-daemon-1.2.2-bin.tar.gz to C:\Users\user\tomcat-build-libs\download-577336155.tar.gz
```

the build.xml was not modified in any way shape or form

my question can be resumed to : where can I find the explicit link to version 1.2.2 so I can change it to 1.2.3
OR
is there any workaround to this?

EDIT:

i have found the link to the version in the properties default file and managed to change it.

it does find the file but now it gives me the error :

```
BUILD FAILED
D:\apache-tomcat-9.0.38-src\build.xml:3055: The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\apache-tomcat-9.0.38-src\build.xml:3402: The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\apache-tomcat-9.0.38-src\build.xml:3350: Checksum check failure for commons-daemon-1.2.3-bin.tar.gz (C:\Users\Thinkpad\tomcat-build-libs\download-1907634559.tar.gz).
  
Algorithm: SHA-512
 
 Expected value: f9fb917aaf398f61c42796eb4168664e076f81bc3fae82790eb39c723f03a1e7cbc2304161938d8d8993b7fbb718214b94740dbf9679f6ef93e85b5a2e861761
 
 Actual values:
 
 SHA-512: 0d7ced8f5d6fd3e8781146ee47c37046c6ccd2f364138f89d137eea5f0255e1b2afae5faf7005164c077087cb08203fd44478d5c14c57c7df449feb324443447
 
 SHA-384: f9107b692d146debcd0f1266f250375324e7dfe9705e2b113b62e40a2f19569f96f3f580e56a557b28e33327f4f565df
 
 SHA-256: 17004f8f79a2618a7fd3604fad4035111c6f3494f3fbf31b9836f9e854b39de9
 
 SHA-1: be7848a5c64fddb184e8a03e2e6e7b4075e70425
 
 MD5: 5ad1f4076c916b719dc29d90c71941e9
```

which in all honesty i have no idea what it means or how to even approach help please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well i fiddled around with the *Build.properties.default* file

the download link for the current versions is in line 96 and the one for the archives is in 97 i do not know why the ant build doesn't try the archives if it fails at using the current version of the files but all it took was to replace the value of base-apache.loc.1
by the value of base-apache.loc.2

it's a hodgepodge and a mess of a solution to be honest but it worked so if anyone has this problem go ahead and try it

Answer (score 0):

will show 404 in browser if you open the link mentioned in the error.
It works for me to change the value of base-apache.loc.1 to https://apache.claz.org in build.properties

Comment: yes someone suggested that i should not link the true links in here so i changed it

Answer (score 0):

'... do not know why the ant build doesn't try the archives if it fails '
I think it is a bug.

workaround

```sh
z@z:~/ps/tomcat$ git diff 
diff --git a/build.properties.default b/build.properties.default
index 879ecc6152..ea944714ee 100644
--- a/build.properties.default
+++ b/build.properties.default
@@ -94,6 +94,7 @@ compile.debug=true
 compile.deprecation=false
 
 base-apache.loc.1=http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.lua?action=download&filename=
+base-apache.loc.1=https://archive.apache.org/dist
 base-apache.loc.2=https://archive.apache.org/dist
 base-commons.loc.1=${base-apache.loc.1}/commons
 base-commons.loc.2=${base-apache.loc.2}/commons
z@z:~/ps/tomcat$ git log --oneline -1
48b6a87171 (HEAD -> 9.0.38, tag: 9.0.38) Tag 9.0.38
```